# Where can I find a specific class in classes.dex?

Tags: android, android-source, dex

I'm trying to understand the Android operating system for my build.

I downloaded the AOSP of my build number.

In `cts/tools/dex-tools/dex/classses.dex` , I found a certain class.

Where in the Android device can I find that class? I'm assuming it will be in an apk?

I greped through the entire downloaded AOSP, but that class doesn't come up.

> So I'm wondering what and where does this dex file compile to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would likely be a part of CTS, which is a separate suite of tests to verify that a build meets many different compatibility requirements. CTS is distributed separately from the firmware, and so you won't find it on the device firmware.